# Pricing Table height issue

Tags: html, wordpress, plugins

I have installed pricing table plugin in my web page. It works fine. But I have faced the height issue problem. Please see the screenshot image. Th detail content is very long compared to others. So other sections were misaligned. All the sections are collapsed. Please help me. Thanks.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: can you provide a link so that we can better troubleshoot your page?

Comment: The files in local path. I need "No of hour" section aligned of 8 and 18 etc..

Comment: Try setting up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the problem. That makes it easy for us to come along, find the issue, and help you solve it. Otherwise we're flying blind.

Comment: we need a link to the page to help.

Comment: Please see the fiddle location: http://jsfiddle.net/PR9am/

Comment: Well, if there is one SINGLE thing the '<table>' tag should be used for is that. The code is using divs and lists for making tables. That's just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This jQuery will get the max height of each li row and set the height to be the same on every li on each row:

```
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};
for (i = 0; i < $("ul li").length; i++) {
//updated as per Sime Vidas comment.
var heights= $("ul li:nth-child(" + (i) + ")").map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get();
var maxHeight = Array.max(heights);
$("ul li:nth-child(" + (i) + ")").css("height", maxHeight);
​}​
```

Here is an update to your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PR9am/1/

Hope it helps.

Comment: You will probably want to put the lists inside another div and update the code, so it doesn't mess up with your other unordered lists... Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PR9am/2/

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add two extra lines to the details list item

```
<li><br>Detail<br>&nbsp;</li>
```

This will put the next row in line with the rest

Comment: Can you explain why you down voted this? It's an easy fix that works.

Comment: It is very unelegant and has to be changed each time the table is updated.